# Rerender of many outputpanels

Tags: visualforce

What is the difference between rerendering one wrapper outputpanel or several outputpanels inside of wrapper? What is the best way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main difference is how much work is done on the server and client. There is no "best way" for any circumstance, and for the most part, won't make any significant difference. The first way generates more server-side code that has to be pushed to the client, while the second way generates more client-side lag as more elements have to be updated. The tipping point depends on how much code is in the middle.

## Outer Wrapper

This is best used when there's little to no intervening code:

```
<apex:outputPanel id="abc">
  <apex:repeat value="{!wrapperlist}" var="wrapper">
    {!wrapper.name}
  </apex:repeat>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

This produces the best performance because there's no "fluff" in the middle, so the number of client-side renders are minimized and the server code is as efficient as possible.

## Inner Wrapper

```
<apex:repeat value="{!wrapperList}" var="wrapper">
  <div class="abc">
    <span class="def">
      Field
    </span>
    <span class="ghi">
      <apex:outputText id="wrapperItem" value="{!wrapper.name}" />
    </span>
    <span class="jkl">
      <apex:commandButton value="Delete" action="{!wrapper.deleterow}">
    </span>
  </div>
</apex:repeat>
```

In this case, we're rendering a lot of components, but most of it is static; by choosing to update only the small bit in the middle, the server's return value is as small as possible, but rendering time will increase slightly. For every large pages with many small updates, this should have better performance.

---

Overall, though, at the end of the day, it usually doesn't matter. Most pages that are big enough where this makes a difference should simply be using a client-side rendering script (jQuery, Angular, etc) with @RemoteAction methods. Otherwise, though, feel free to use whichever is easier to read and maintain. The overall performance won't matter much.